# Can't catch Flutter exception in GoogleSignIn

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in a Flutter application but all the exception that I try to catch are not being caught. I don't know why. I have tried different methots to catch them but nothing.

This is my code:

```
Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
    try {
      googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn().then((res) {
        print("success");
        return null;
      }, onError: (e) {
        print("${e.toString()}");
        return null;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print("${err.toString()}");
    }
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
  }
```

The exception is always thrown on line `googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn()`

As you can see I try to catch exceptions in many ways but none of them actually works.

Comment: Actually I discovered that if i run with "start debugging" (with VS Code) I have the problem I said but if I do "start without debugging" I'm able to catch the exception

Comment: What makes you think, that the exception is not caught ?

Comment: @Thomas vs code stops with a big red message and application freezes

Comment: did you follow the introductions at 'https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in'? What is the error message? I guess it crashes because of an underlying error (e.g. no google-services.json file). Pretty sure it will not freeze because of not catching the error (which you do anyways - twice).

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem with your sample code and its the `.then` call ...

```
googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn().then((res) {
        print("success");
        return null;
      }, onError: (e) {
        print("${e.toString()}");
        return null;
      });
```

you cannot do both an `await` and a `.then` typically its one or the other.  For the try/catch to work remove the `.then`

```
try {
    googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
} catch(err) {
  ...
}
```